# How to apply opacity to text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: html, css

The following fiddle fades out the text correctly, but the ellipsis remains opaque.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/TJ7A9/

```
<div id="incorrect">
    <span>Incorrect</span>
</div>
```

```css
#incorrect { 
    width: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; }
#incorrect span { opacity: .25; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The display properties of the `...` added from `text-overflow: ellipsis` seem to inherit from the element that it is defined on. Simply move the definition to the semi-transparent element.

```css
overflow      : hidden;
width         : 100%;
text-overflow : ellipsis;
display       : inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/TJ7A9/2/

```css
#correct { width: 50px;}
#correct span { 
    opacity: .25;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Yes, that's because the string is added as a last inline child element of its containing block. In the incorrect example, it appears within the div, as a following sibling of the span, so the opacity on the span does not apply to it.